# How to check for a (date?) variable in a url before allowing access to site

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite

Building a site (in Drupal) that can only be linked to and viewed by members of a separate site (asp).

The URL to the Drupal site will only be visible to members on the asp site but I don't want them to copy and paste that URL and share it with non-members.

So... how do I make that URL constantly changing and distinct (i.e. current date?) and how do I have the Drupal site check to see that the URL is coming from the member site only?

I was thinking an .htaccess file could check for certain variables in the URL.. but A) don't know how to add a changeable variable to the URL and B) don't know the mod rewirte rule to check for that variable in the URL

Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient a deterrent it would be.. but [time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) will return the current date which you can then append to your url.

Most web browsers pass the HTTP_REFERER variable by default, but in many this behaviour can be changed to not show it or to pass something else instead. There is also 3rd party anti-spyware etc software that can be installed on a user's computer which also prevents the referrer information from being passed to the web server. Because it can also be changed to something else, the HTTP_REFERER cannot be trusted, but it is still useful for working out where people have come from.

Copied from electrictoolbox.com [read more here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/)